# Android wireless display

Tags: android

I'm a fairly new android programmer and I've been having a rummage online about displaying an android screen over the network. I know it is possible to mirror the display using apps such as MirrorOp Sender. What I'm looking for is the android device to display one thing on the android device itself and something completely different on a screen elsewhere. So far my search results haven't gotten me very far.

So really what I want to know is, are there currently apps out there that can do this and are there any libraries out there that I could use to help me implement this? I have a few ideas on how I would go about implementing this but there is no point in me writing something from scratch if it has already been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 4.2 adds [support for different content on multiple displays](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#SecondaryDisplays).

While it is theoretically possible for you to do this at the app level on earlier versions of Android, I am not aware of any apps that do, and it may be difficult for you to be compliant with relevant wireless standards (e.g., Miracast).

Note that MirrorOp Sender requires root access and uses techniques that may or may not work on all Android devices.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew about those standards. Useful to know.